# facebookads api async job check status and get the result later

Tags: google-app-engine, facebook-ads-api, google-app-engine-python

submitted the job to in async mode to pull the ad insights data from facebook by using facebookads api.

```
r = ad_account.get_insights(params=params, async=True)
```

Stored the report_run_id

I want to check the status of this job in different python code and pull the result in that script instead of same script.

If it is in the same job, I know how to check the status and get the result.

```
  while  r[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100: 
           time.sleep(5)
           r.remote_read()
   result = r.get_result()
```

in other words, If I have  data (it has report_run_id column). How to check the job status and get the result.

Planning to move this script to google appengine, google appengine has 60sec time out window. So I need to check the job status later point of time and if the job is success pull the data and load into BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can download the report from the following url. Need to replace the report_run_id and access_token.

Check whether the report is ready or not with the following url :

"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/"+report_run_id+"?fields=async_status,async_percent_completion&appsecret_proof="+config['appsecret_proof']+"&access_token="+config['access_token']+"&app_secret="+config['app_secret']

Download the report with the following URL:

"https://www.facebook.com/ads/ads_insights/export_report?report_run_id="+report_run_id+"&format=csv&access_token="+config['access_token']